# JSON Object Mapping - RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, restkit

I have the below JSON as response. How can I do object mapping for it? I am using iOS - RestKit.

```
    {  
   "predictions":[  
      {  
         "description":"User1",
         "id":"75b8c57b4443f4b881f0efc94afd52437232aee9"
      },
      {  
         "description":"User2",
         "id":"82aa3303704041cda0e4fc34024d383dbf923604"
      },
      {  
         "description":"User3",
         "id":"f88f669a30934ef599bccf86c0236426cf2d313e"
      },
      {  
         "description":"User4",
         "id":"fa9ae7b65fa52bffdabf00d69e7db5cd37539781"
      },
      {  
         "description":"User5",
         "id":“66df3fd7e400eb31efd3ac935036aab2c02b03f0"
      }
   ],
   "status":"OK"
}
```

Comment: Check the following tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/58682/introduction-restkit-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class called `Prediction` with `description` and `predictionId` as properties and then use the mapper object

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Prediction class]]; [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
@"description":   @"description",
@"id":     @"predictionId",
}];
```

of course after you parse the response correctly

Comment: I am using the same. But there is no response.